# Wordpress Twenty Eleven theme footer widgets

Tags: wordpress, widget, footer

I'm currently using the twenty eleven theme and I have managed to add a fourth footer widget fine using a tutorial online and everything works perfectly.

Now i'm looking to reduce the size of and spacing between each widget individually. I have done some extensive searching and tried pretty much everything I can think off using css to achieve this to no avail.

any help would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you have an example site?
every widget should have it's own ID. Use those to style them using css
http://twentyelevendemo.wordpress.com/ - here is a demo of twenty eleven.
in the footer you have

Comment: I only have a local version. sadly. I will post the coding up when I get a sec.

Comment: the css is here;


`#supplementary.four .widget-area {
 float: left;
 margin-right: 3.7%;
 width: 22.18%;
}

supplementary.four .widget-area {
 float: left;
 margin-right: 3.7%;
 width: 1.18%;
}

#supplementary.four .widget-area + .widget-area + .widget-area + .widget-area {
 margin-right: 0;
}

#supplementary {
 border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 margin: 0;
}`

Comment: sorry I cant get it to display clearly in the comments section

Comment: add float left and width  on .four instead of .widget-area